AWS ALB / Lambda - http Head call issue
In AWS, I have a ALB that calls a Lambda, a simple JS function that then makes an http call to my backend service in ECS, the lambda then simply returns the answer of the BE Service.
I have logs on both and the interaction happens as expected. The lambda is required to act as a sort of ngnix to dispatch/transfrom the request if needed.
But in the case of a HEAD call, the ALB seems to overwrite the header 'content-length' to be the size of the body, which in a HEAD call is 0 (empty/null) which loses the whole point of the HEAD call...
Here is the request logged in my lambda :
{
    "requestContext": {
        "elb": {
            "targetGroupArn": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    },
    "httpMethod": "HEAD",
    "path": "/tests/testID/topics/1234",
    "queryStringParameters": {},
    "headers": {
        "accept": "*/*",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "authorization": "Basic xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "connection": "keep-alive",
        "host": "abc.zerty.com",
        "postman-token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "user-agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.43.0",
        "x-amzn-trace-id": "Root=1-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "x-forwarded-for": "100.128.128.127",
        "x-forwarded-port": "443",
        "x-forwarded-proto": "https"
    },
    "body": "",
    "isBase64Encoded": false
}

Here is the answer of my BE Service loged in my Lambda :
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "accept": "*/*",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "authorization": "Basic xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "connection": "keep-alive, keep-alive",
        "host": "abc.zerty.com",
        "postman-token": "xxxxxxxxx",
        "user-agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.43.0",
        "x-amzn-trace-id": "Root=1-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx6",
        "x-forwarded-for": "100.128.128.127",
        "x-forwarded-port": "443",
        "x-forwarded-proto": "https",
        "accept-ranges": "bytes",
        "content-length": "116261",
        "date": "Mon, 02 Dec 2024 10:41:31 GMT",
        "keep-alive": "timeout=60"
    },
    "body": ""
}

Postman response header :
Server: awselb/2.0
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
keep-alive: timeout=60
date: Mon, 02 Dec 2024 12:48:08 GMT
accept-ranges: bytes
x-forwarded-proto: https
x-forwarded-port: 443
x-forwarded-for: 100.128.128.127
x-amzn-trace-id: Root=1-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
user-agent: PostmanRuntime/7.43.0
postman-token: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
host: abc.zerty.com
authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxx
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept: /
In Postman where I test this interaction the content-length is always 0 for this call.
Since the BE is correct then the Lambda (test in Local also without ALB) return the right value in the Header, I'm deducting the issue comes from the ALB manipulating the response header.
Here is the relevant part of code for my Lambda (some business logic is absent but not relevant, no request nor response manipulation are done)  :
const http = require('http');

function handleError(err) {
  if (err instanceof Error) {
    return err.message;
  }
  return JSON.stringify(err);
}

module.exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  try {
    
    let serviceUrl = process.env.SERVICE_B_URL;
    const url = new URL(serviceUrl);
    const normalizedPath = (url.pathname + event.path).replace(/\/{2,}/g, '/');

    const options = {
      hostname: url.hostname,
      port: url.port || 80,
      path: normalizedPath,
      method: event.httpMethod,
      headers: event.headers,
    };

// Make HTTP call and wait for the response
    const response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
        let responseBody = '';

        // Capture response headers
        const responseHeaders = res.headers;

        // Log response headers
        console.log('Response Headers:', JSON.stringify(responseHeaders, null, 2));

        res.on('data', (chunk) => {
          responseBody += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', () => {
          console.log('Response Status Code:', res.statusCode);
          console.log('Response Body:', responseBody);

          resolve({
            statusCode: res.statusCode,
            headers: res.headers,
            body: responseBody,
          });
        });
      });

      req.on('error', (e) => {
        reject({
          statusCode: 500,
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
          body: JSON.stringify({ error: handleError(e) }),
        });
      });

      if (event.body) {
        req.write(event.body);
      }
      req.end();
    });
    console.log('Response Object Details:', JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));

    return response

  } catch (error) {
    const unexpectedErrorMessage = handleError(error);
        console.error('Unexpected Error:', unexpectedErrorMessage);

        // Use callback to return an error response
        callback(null, {
          statusCode: 500,
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
          body: JSON.stringify({ error: unexpectedErrorMessage }),
        });
  }
};

Does anyone has an idea how to fix this interaction ? I did not see any documentation regarding the ALB overwrite of header. It might be an issue with the JSON that I send back to the ALB but I don't see it.
